# Is pastry still used?

Tags: distributed-computing, p2p, distributed-system, dht, pastry

I recently tried to find an implementation of the Pastry DHT but couldn't find an active source. I think this was the largest implementation https://www.freepastry.org/ but the last stable release was in 2009. Is pastry still used and is the free pastry implementation abandonded. Also what are the alternatives for Pastry used today ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it doesn't work now. I tried it before, but I give up and use libtorrent now.